# What is the Basis in Law that an "Investigation 'Quid Pro Quo'" is Unlawful or Unconstitutional?

Tags: constitutional-law, elections, investigation, obstruction, foreign-relations

In cases of investigating election fraud, there seems to be a potential for a conflict of interest no matter who investigates it.

So, why can't the White House investigate campaign issues (involving the Ukraine, Clintons, and Bidens), regardless of any perceived conflict of interest?

**How is it unlawful/unconstitutional for a President to *order Executive Branch employees to* investigate election fraud, (or if they were to solicit foreign allies to do the same with reciprocity)?**

Suppose that any given sets of facts regarding President Trump's actions are true and constitute "basis in fact".  But, what would be the "basis in law" to impeach over those acts?

Aren't these types of negotiations expected of heads of state?

Comment: Current events do not concern an investigation *by the president* nor by any other officer of the US government.  Rather, they concern the president requiring another country to undertake an investigation as a condition of receiving military aid that was already allocated.

Comment: @elika kohen What do your first two sentences have to do with the rest of your post?

Comment: @phoog - How does a head of state negotiating like that subjected to accusations of illegality?  Isn't it normal for heads of state to do that?   I honestly don't understand the basis in law for any of these accusations, (let alone basis in fact).

Comment: Whether it violates any law is not directly relevant. It's entirely improper. But this isn't exactly a negotiation: the aid was already approved. If the president has evidence that someone broke US laws, then he should pass the evidence to the US Attorney General.  If there's evidence that someone broke Ukrainian laws, then he *may* give that information to Ukraine and ask Ukraine to investigate.  But withholding congressionally mandated foreign aid to achieve personal ends is possibly a violation of the oath of office and certainly abuse of power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Conflict of interest" has a specific meaning w.r.t. various [federal laws](https://www.imls.gov/sites/default/files/federal-conflict-interest-statutes.pdf), which have financial gain as their underpinning. The so-called conflict which your referring to is an abstract moral duty, eforced at the polls every few years: there is no conflict of interest.

"Obstruction of justice" is defined in [18 USC 73](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-73). The law does not require a person to passively submit to an investigation, thus you can file motions with a competent court to resist a subpoena. If there is a [criminal investigation of a US criminal statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1510), it is illegal to

> willfully endeavors by means of bribery to obstruct, delay, or prevent
>   the communication of information relating to a violation of any
>   criminal statute

Saying "you don't have authority to tell me to do that" is not obstruction of justice.

I have not seen any (credible) claim that it is unconstitutional for the president to order an investigation of election fraud, for example 
[Executive Order 13799](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13799). That commission was disbanded, but a new commission could be ordered via the same mechanism. Congress has the power to defund any such commission, and there was an unsuccessful attempt to use that power in the previous instance.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some confusion here between unconstitutional and just plain unlawful. Even leaving aside whether the President needs to order the Attorney General to perform the investigative steps, with respect to the various election issues that have arisen the current Administration, there have been significant potential problems with existing law.

If you are referring to the commission headed by Kris Kobach, whose ostensible purpose was finding votes cast by ineligible persons, they had significant problems with data privacy protected by law. There was also a strong whiff of racial discrimination that would be prohibited by the 14th Amendment.

If you are referring to the various entanglements between President Trump and Ukraine, there's the Budget and Impoundment Control Act of 1974 (colloquially, the Anti-Impoundment Act), extortion, bribery, and false accusation issues.

Perhaps the OP can be more specific about where the Constitution is coming into play in the investigation?

Comment: In the abstract, there isn't anything in the _Constitution_ preventing such an order. However, the specific requests that Trump made may have broken a number of ordinary _laws_. The President is not exempt from the operation of the law in our system; and this was already true at the time we became independent of Great Britain. Accepting (much less eliciting) campaign contributions from foreign governments is unlawful. See also the other laws I already cited.

Comment: "If you are referring to the various entanglements between President Trump and Ukraine, there's the Budget and Impoundment Control Act of 1974 (colloquially, the Anti-Impoundment Act), extortion, bribery, and false accusation issues."  Is this the actual basis in law for the current impeachment proceedings?   If so, could you explain that?  If so, this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Impeachment, unlike a traditional indictment, doesn't have to cite a particular section of law. Especially with the sworn opening statement of David Holmes (taken Nov 15), there's strong evidence that Trump personally ordered aid that Congress had authorized to be held up until the Ukrainian Government announced an investigation into the Bidens, regardless of the absence of any legitimate reason to do such an investigation. Bribery, extortion, and illegal impoundment are all in play, as is "abuse of power", which isn't a specific named crime.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So, in cases of investigating election fraud, why couldn't the White House investigate campaign issues (involving the Ukraine, Clintons, and Bidens), regardless of any perceived conflict of interest? How is it unconstitutional for a President to investigate election fraud?

Because that office doesn’t have that power - the Attorney General does.

> 2. If the Executive Branch cannot pursue these investigations, who can? Isn't there conflict of interest all-around?

The Executive Branch (Department of Justice) *can*, the Executive Branch (President) can’t.

> 3. Couldn't actions stalling these investigations also be considered obstructions of justice?

Obstructing an legal investigation might be illegal, stopping an illegal one isn’t.

Comment: He is not the Secretary of Justice. Any citizen, even POTUS, can investigate to their heart's content: the apt question is whether POTUS can use executive power in this case. The power he has is to direct the AG to...

Comment: The department of justice is unique among US executive departments in that its head does not bear the title "secretary" but rather "attorney general."

Comment: Are there any references for why the executive branch cannot order the justice department to do this?   What is the distinction here?

Comment: @elikakohen because it’s a democracy, not an autocracy. The President can *ask* the AG, not *order*, but the AG has to decide if such an investigation is warranted and legal.

Comment: @DaleM - I understand what you are saying.  I was just wondering if that is a law, or something, documented some place.  More than that, doesn't the president order the FBI, CIA, etc.?   Couldn't the CIA, or even the President himself, investigate by using diplomacy to get information from a foreign power?

Comment: @elikakohen The Department of Justice and the Attorney General are in the Executive Branch, so your question is whether the *Executive* (the President) can give order to Executive Branch employees. Asked that way, the answer should be obvious.

Comment: @DaleM An American would say you have it exactly backwards: Because the US is a democracy, not an autocracy, unelected officials such as the AG, answer to elected officials, such as the President, who in turn answers to the citizens through elections. An AG who disagrees with the President can resign, as in the Saturday Night Massacre, and a President who asks the AG to do corrupt things can be voted out of office, or impeached.

Comment: @Justaguy “just following orders” is not any part of a democratic system. The correct role of any official asked to do something illegal is to say no. This applies as much to a soldier on a battlefield as to the AG.

Comment: @DaleM but an AG who has been ordered by the president to do something illegal (for the president can indeed issue such an order) has no recourse other than resigning or defying the order and waiting for the consequences, which could be as severe as dismissal.

Comment: @phoog and a soldier who has been given an illegal order has no option to resign - they can just wait for their court martial. And their consequences if they’re wrong are way worse than dismissal.

Comment: @DaleM But the soldier has an opportunity to defend against dismissal or other negative consequences by arguing that the order was unlawful.  The AG has no such recourse.  Further, I don't see how the military analogy supports the assertion in a comment that "the President can ask the AG, not order."  Why can't the president order the AG to undertake an investigation?

Comment: @phoog of course he can ask, just like your boss can ask you to do something illegal. If you refuse you might be fired, if you comply you might be jailed. It’s a free country - make your choice.

Comment: @DaleM My point is that you've said the president cannot "order" the AG, and that is as far as I can tell incorrect.  It seems rather that such orders are fairly routine.

Comment: @phoog Perhaps we are talking at cross-purposes. My point is the AG has their own legal obligations that take precedence over a request/order from the President.